# How to know if a windows 8 device(laptop/tablet/desktop) is GPS capable

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, winrt-async

I am developing a Windows 8 Store app in xaml and it uses user's GPS location.IS there any way I can know programmatically if the device user is using has GPS capability ?

Unlike Windows phone it only works when there is internet connection ?

Answer (score 2):

You need to check the status of the location sensor

```
var location = new Geolocator();

if(location.LocationStatus == PositionStatus.NotAvailable)
{
     //Do Something
}
else
{
     //Do Something else
}
```

Following article covers `Geolocation` topic really nicely

http://www.jeffblankenburg.com/2012/11/14/31-days-of-windows-8-day-14-geolocation/

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to check the sensor state.

- `NotSupported` The sensor hardware is unavailable.
- `Ready` The sensor is available and resolving data.
- `Initializing` The sensor is available and initializing.
- `NoData` The sensor is unable to obtain data.
- `NoPermissions` The caller does not have permission to access the
  sensor’s data.
- `Disabled` The sensor is disabled.

Comment: hey Daniel, nice to see you on StackOverflow :)